# Common table references, Int or String identifier?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, user-permissions

I was wondering how to take the best way to solve this situation. It's a database structure problem... Let's see the case.

I have some databases which have the same structure (let's say db_A, db_B, db_C). They are identical in structure but with different data, of course.

There's another database with permissions (db_permissions), and another with users (db_users).

The db_permissions structure table would be *ID, permission*; where *permission* is a unique string identifier (like *post:create*).

Now, there's a user which has different permissions on each table. For example: *user 123* would have rights to write a post in *db_A*, rights to only read posts on *db_B*, and rights to read, write and delete posts on *db_C*.

My question is, how should I reference the permissions on each table?

- Do I **reference the unique string identifier** (like post:create, post:read) and add this directly to each database permissions (like *user_id - permission_string*)?
- Or do I reference them **by the ID primary key on the permissions** database (like *user_id - permission_id*)?

In my PHP script, when I check the permissions, I check by the unique string identifier.

What would you recommend? Would you use another structure for the permissions?

Thanks for your time and answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `permissions` table that maps IDs to permission strings, then you should use those IDs in other tables that store user permissions.

You should have a `table_permissions` table, with 3 columns: `user_ID`, `table_ID`, `permission_ID`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think it's the better solution too!

Answer (score 0):

Indexes / references should always be type integer if you want to keep performance